# Was Obi-Wan speciest?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Obi-Wan Kenobi's master was killed by a Dathomirian native Darth Maul in front of him. Later in *Clone Wars* S03E14(not S13E14), when Maul's brother Savage starts a Jedi killing spree, upon seeing a holorecording of him, Obi-Wan mistakes him for Darth Maul. Later during the investigation of this, while interrogating a Night Mother, he calls him an animal.

In addition to that, he calls Tuskens "Sand People" in *The New Hope*.

Does Obi-Wan have specially motivated hate towards Dathomirians and/or other non-human species (potentially due to his traumatic encounter with Darth Maul and the sheer amount of other confrontations)?

Obviously, I expect official information, not opinions.

Comment: It's possible, of course, but perhaps Obi-Wan dislikes Maul because he's an evil Sith Lord, and mistakes Savage for Maul because they're brothers?

Comment: @Adamant I don't remember Obi-Wan getting that emotional about pursuing a sith lord before, usually he is the cool contrast to Anakin. Also, Savage has got a different skin color, different space and a different body shape and horns(enhanced by night sister magic).

Comment: Perhaps it might have something to do with Maul having killed his mentor? And as for Savage, it could be that Obi-Wan thinks that "all Dathomirians look alike," but it would be very hard to not notice that Savage looked different from Maul. Best guess, their facial features are close (them being brothers), so Obi thought it had to be Maul, having upgraded himself somehow.

Comment: I wouldn’t say this is opinion-based at all. Think about all the questions we’ve had about whether the Empire was prejudiced against non-humans (it was). There may or may not be information out there, but that’s no different from many of our questions.

Comment: The problem with this question is that no matter how objective we try to be in our answers, it's still not going to be anything official. **Who's to say what the 'correct' answer is?** Therefore, I'm voting to leave closed at this point.

Comment: You might wish to note that the Tuskens (in the canon Star Wars: From a Certain Point of View) refer to themselves as Sand People on multiple occasions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67209/discussion-on-question-by-worse-username-was-obi-wan-speciest).

Comment: @Möoz If we don't know the answer, that doesn't make the question POB or unclear. There are several meta posts about this (most recently [this one](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11329/31394), closed as a double dupe), always with the same conclusion. "We don't know" is an **answer**, not a reason to close.

Comment: "Sand people" looks quite a neutral name, I did not get an impression that it is a pejorative in-universe.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I wasn't saying we may not know, I was saying that the user is inviting our opinion-based answers by not tightening up the scope with official sources.

Comment: wait sand people isn't their real name? I never knew I had been racist all these years

Comment: Why did so many people downvote this question? It's quite interesting and rather good.

Comment: The edit is too short for me to propose, but I think this is supposed to say [**S3E14**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Witches_of_the_Mist), not S13E14. _The Clone Wars_ didn't have 13 seasons.

Comment: @reirab good catch, thanks.

Comment: It should be noted that the hologram Kenobi sees of Savage is blue, explaining how he thinks it could be Maul even though Maul and Savage are different colors.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that since Maul and Savage are brothers, they look similar. It is an easy error to make.

Also, Obi-wan served with Jedi of countless species during, and prior to the Clone Wars. He respected all of them.

Comment: As for the Tuskens, I have the idea at everyone calls them Sand People.

Comment: From looking up Savage, it seems like his face is yellow, not red. Not that that makes Obi-Wan some kind of space nazi or anything.

Comment: @Paul The recording of Savage Obi-Wan sees is blue, hiding Savage's skin tone.

Answer (score 0):

Tusken Raiders and Dathomirians are humanoid extra terrestrials, so they are not humans, but the Dathomirians do have equal status as humans in the Star Wars universe. But that would just be like mistaking an enemy for a random person you meet. The Tusken Raiders would be like an aggressive Stone Age tribe. The title “Sand People” is very generous. Obi Wan/Ben Kenobi is (drumroll) not speciest.